# How to run a query where it displays all items of a XML node?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

```
<DataItem name="xxxxx" value="2" />
<Roles>
  <Role id="Role1" />
  <Role id="Role2" />
  <Role id="Role3" />
  <Role id="Role4" />
</Roles>
```

This XML is in table A, column Z.

How would I go about writing a query to see all roles in this XML?

Example:

```
SELECT Z FROM A
```

Result:

```
Role1
Role2
Role3   
Role4
```

I also need to take into account that the roles are DYNAMIC ... I never know how many there will be in there.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server, so T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T.N.value('@id', 'varchar(10)')
from A
  cross apply Z.nodes('/Roles/Role') as T(N)
```

[xml Data Types Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

Comment: Mike, not sure if I'm understanding what you put. I'm assuming "T.N" should be the XML column name, which in my case is "XmlDoc" ... I'm just not understanding where Z is coming from as well as what T(N) means?

Comment: SELECT  [XmlDoc].value('@id', 'varchar(10)')
FROM    [table]
CROSS APPLY [XmlDoc].nodes('/Roles/Role') ... im getting an error: Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The object name 'TABLE.XmlDoc.nodes' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.

Comment: Z comes from your question where you said z is a column in A. Z is the column holding your XML. T is a table alias for the cross apply and N is the column that holds a pointer to the shredded XML.